# Why is my web notification badge still showing generic chrome icon or blank even after customization?

Tags: service-worker, web-notifications

I'm trying to display a notification message from the service worker in a progressive web app(PWA) with a custom badge icon.

[example of notification with custom badge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjZLb.png)

```js
 self.registration.showNotification("Title", {
    icon: [path/to/icon],
    badge: [path/to/badge],
    body: "My message",
  });
```

I understand that I'm supposed to use an alpha image but depending on the icon I use, I either get the generic chrome Icon or a blank square.

I have tried using the following icons...

[black icon with white background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wakrs.png)

[white icon with black background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SF9QM.png)

Comment: "The badge must be a PNG image and will be masked automatically: for this reason we recommend to draw a shape over a transparent background." ([source](https://pushpad.xyz/docs/sending_images)). I think that your issue is that the images have a white background, instead of a transparent background. I have some sites that use a badge with transparent PNG and it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

After spending hours turning the internet upside down and trying different icons, I learned that while rendering the icon to use, I had to export the alpha channel only hence a white icon with a transparent background in .png format.

Thanks to [these](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v7.0/docs/web-push-notification-icons#badge-requirements) docs

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).